# onSkipToNext using MediaControllerCompat in MediaBrowserServiceCompat (Service Class)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I'm skipping to next song using following code line in my activity's media player. Below solution works for such situation.

```
MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController((MainActivity) context).getTransportControls().skipToNext();
```

However the problem I have right now is, I'm implementing a notification player in a Service (extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat) class. I need to implement next, previous in this notification player.

As I cannot get the activity as given above within a service. How can we achieve the same using a service class.